# Oracle: Invalid identifier

Tags: oracle

Can anyone explain to me why I get a 00904 error when I run the following

```
SELECT "OASM"."DT_GROUPEPG".GROUPEPGID,
  "OASM"."DT_GROUPEPG".GROUPID,
  "OASM"."DT_GROUPEPG".EPGID,
  "OASM"."DT_GROUPEPG".ZAPID,
  "OASM"."LU_EPG".LASTREADTIME,
  "OASM"."LU_EPG".SERVICE_NAME,
  "OASM"."LU_EPG".SOURCE_ID,
  "OASM"."LU_EPG".ONID,
  "OASM"."LU_EPG".TSID,
  "OASM"."LU_EPG".SID,
  "OASM"."LU_EPG".TYPE_ID,
  "OASM"."LU_EPG".OPERATOR_ID,
  "OASM"."LU_EPG".URL 
FROM "OASM"."DT_GROUPEPG"
INNER JOIN "OASM"."LU_EPG"
ON "OASM"."DT_GROUPEPG".EPGID = "OASM"."LU_EPG".EPGID
ORDER BY LastReadTime;
```

I'm still new to Oracle, and was of the impression that, because Oracle executes blocks of statements, and not line by line, that doing this kind of query would be valid? The error currently fires at the OPERATOR_ID line, but removing/commenting it out just moves the erro up a line, until all the LU_EPG table references are removed

Comment: can you try a `SELECT * FROM "OASM"."LU_EPG"`, with and without quotes ? And show LU_EPG structure ? And the result of `select table_name from all_tables where UPPER(table_name) = 'LU_EPG'`

Comment: I've just tried them and both return full datasets of 350+ rows. Table name returns as LU_EPG. How do you want me to show the structure?

Comment: Interesting: I get `ERROR: object LU_EPG does not exist `

Comment: So, can you retry your question's query, changing just the last line by  `ORDER BY OASM.LU_EPG.LASTREADTIME` (don't use double quotes if not needed)

Comment: Tried it, I still get the `invalid identifier` error, but this time focused on `lastreadtime`.

Comment: Ok, shorcut missed ;) so try `desc oasm.lu_epg`

Comment: Thanks, Raphaël. Using this command has highlighted my issue (correct column, wrong table). I do apologize for wasting your time on a problem that should never have existed, but thank you for all of your help :)

Comment: No prob, my time is not SO precious ;)

Comment: In addition to that, try getting rid of the double quotes `"` from the schema name and table names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't (and don't need to) specify the schema name when referring to the columns. Also, I recommend you use table aliases (e.g. `a` and `b` in the example below):

```
SELECT a.GROUPEPGID,
  a.GROUPID,
  a.EPGID,
  a.ZAPID,
  b.LASTREADTIME,
  b.SERVICE_NAME,
  b.SOURCE_ID,
  b.ONID,
  b.TSID,
  b.SID,
  b.TYPE_ID,
  b.OPERATOR_ID,
  b.URL 
FROM "OASM"."DT_GROUPEPG" a
INNER JOIN "OASM"."LU_EPG" b
ON a.EPGID = b.EPGID
ORDER BY b.LastReadTime;
```